# Spring Batch Retry Policy Suspend Thread on Custom Tasklet

Tags: multithreading, spring-batch

```
<batch:job id="partitionjob">
    <batch:step id="partitionedLoadStep">
        <batch:partition step="task" partitioner="filePartitioner">
            <batch:handler grid-size="10" />
        </batch:partition>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="filePartitioner"
      class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.MultiResourcePartitioner"
      scope="step">
    <property name="resources" value="file:/SpringBatch/inputFiles/test/test*.txt" />
</bean>

<batch:step id="task">
    <batch:tasklet ref="simpleTasklet"/>
</batch:step>
```

I am working on a proof of concept using Spring Batch. The job above takes a number of files as input and for each file executes the TaskletStep. In my 'simpleTasklet' above I'd like to have the ability to suspend the current thread if certain resources aren't available. For example, if I have 100 input files, and the first 5 can't proceed until resources are available I would still want the next 10 files to proceed. I'd like some retry mechanism in the tasklet but I also want the thread to be suspended versus holding onto it until it is retried.

I've done a lot of researching and I don't seem to be able to find a viable solution. Any ideas would be helpful. Thank you

Comment: Just to confirm, you really don't want to suspend the thread...you want to suspend the work on that thread, freeing the thread itself up, correct?  Also, can you provide an example of how resources for one file would not be enough to process it but others should be processed?

Comment: Yes, I want to free up the thread. The idea is that each file is going to be uploaded using an API. Each file represents a different account, some accounts will be available to be uploaded and some not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, I'd propose a slightly different approach.  Right now, your partitioned approach creates one partition per file which, in essence, gives you one shot at executing the tasklet within the current `JobExecution`.  This prevents you from skipping the item and trying it again later in the same `JobExecution`.

Instead, I'd propose using a reader/writer approach instead of the custom `Tasklet`.  The reader would identify the files that need to be uploaded based on the resource specification you pass (similar to how the MultiResourcePartitioner works).  The reader would then, on each call to `ItemReader#read()` return the name of the next file to read.  The `ItemWriter#write()` would then do the upload and mark the file as being uploaded somewhere (move it to another directory, rename it, etc).  The reader would re-present files that have not been uploaded to the `ItemWriter` until they were successfully uploaded and marked as such.

The above approach could be multi-threaded in a number of ways and prevent the difficulties of managing to pause and restart work in a way that doesn't follow Spring Batch patterns.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try to implement it like this.

Comment: Another question on a similar note. Let's say I have a job that uses remote partitioning. If the step fails on one of the slaves can it be retried on another? Or is the only way to 'retry' failures to restart the job?

Comment: Yes if configured correctly.  Take a look at the video here for a demo of that functionality: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYTj5YT7CZU